# Docker Desktop Dev Environment permission denied on script?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

### Enviroment

I'm new to docker and am trying to setup my project in the new Docker Desktop - Dev Environment feature as a compose project.

### Problem

In my compose file I'm setting up a dev mongo server that needs to be initialized as a replicaSet. This requires executing a few commands in mongosh and I have as a separate script. The way I have it works when checked out as a local directory but does not work when Docker Desktop pulls from git directly.

When it's creating the mongo-setup it fails due to permissions:

```
Container mongo-setup  Starting
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/scripts/mongosetup.sh": permission denied: unknown
exit status 1
```

I removed the entry script so the container booted and CLI'd into it. The file does exist, so how do I correct the permissions so that it works? I don't want to have to manually enter the container to change its permissions.

[image]

### Alternative

Other solutions for this are using the healthcheck to run the command. This however, while works with docker-compose up doesn't work in Docker Desktop Dev Enviroments:

```
healthcheck:
      test: test $$(echo "rs.initiate().ok || rs.status().ok" | mongo  --quiet) -eq 1
      interval: 10s
```

This errors out with saying $ needs to be escaped. Doesn't matter how many $ I put. From what I can tell, docker desktop generates its own devenv-docker-compose.yaml from the original docker-compose.yaml and there's a parsing issue with the escaped characters.

### Test Repo that fails

https://github.com/jrj2211/mongo-docker-test

### Setup Images

[image]

[image]

### Files

```
# File: .docker/docker-compose.yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongo-setup:
    container_name: mongo-setup
    image: mongo
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      default:
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/scripts/mongosetup.sh:/scripts/mongosetup.sh
    entrypoint: [ "/scripts/mongosetup.sh" ]
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
  mongodb:
    hostname: mongodb
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:5.0.9
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: test
      MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME: rs0
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]

volumes:
  mongo-data:
```

```
# File: .docker/scripts/mongosetup.sh
#!/bin/bash

MONGODB1=mongodb

echo "Waiting for startup.."
until curl http://${MONGODB1}:27017/serverStatus\?text\=1 2>&1 | grep uptime | head -1; do
  printf '.'
  sleep 1
done

echo Executing setup at `date +"%T" `
mongosh --quiet --host ${MONGODB1}:27017 <<EOF
rs.initiate();
db.getMongo().setReadPref('primaryPreferred');
rs.status();
EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at my "ls -la" of the file its not executable. Changing my entry point to include "sh" did the trick. I also set the user as root but not sure if that was necessary:

```
entrypoint: ["sh", "/scripts/mongosetup.sh" ]
user: root
```

It does sound like this has some drawbacks if you have a more complicated script where some features are not available.

I'd still be curious if there are any other ways to set this as executable from the docker-compose file.